# bool operator() and inheritance

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, compiler-errors

I have the following problem with bool operator() for derived class

Base class

```
class Point
{
double x, y;
public:
Point(){x=0;y=0;}
...
}
```

Derived class

```
class 3DPoint : public Point
{
double z;
public:
3DPoint(double x, double y, double zx) : Point(x,y){z(zz);}
...
}
```

operator () for derived class

```
class compareByX
{
bool operator () (const 3DPoint *p1, const 3DPoint *p2) const
{
return p1->x < p2->x;   //Compilation error
}
}
```

Container of points

```
class List: public list<3DPoint *>
{
...
}


int main()
{
List l;;
l.push_back(new 3DPoint(1,2,3));
l.push_back(new 3DPoint(4,5,6));
sort(l.begin(), l.end(), compareByX);  
}
```

The compilation stops in class compareByX with the following message: can not convert 3DPoint const to Point. I removed const declaration...

```
class compareByX
{
bool operator () (3DPoint *p1, 3DPoint *p2) const
{
return p1->x < p2->x;   //Compilation error
}
}
```

... and... successful compilation. But I believe that operator () is not well defined. Can you help me, please? Perhaps it would be better to propose more suitable object model... Thanx.

Comment: 3DPoint? Identifiers can't start with a digit.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not C#. Looks like C++?

Comment: @Michael Stum: Yes, so I assumed. And fixed the tags.

Comment: That should be `sort(l.begin(), l.end(), compareByX());`

Comment: @Ian If you don't post the real code, using copy and paste NOT retyping it, you won't get  a real answer.

Comment: In general it is a good idea to reduce the problem to the smallest piece of code that reproduces it. Either post the original problem (usually too large for a question) or create a piece of code that replicates exactly your problem. The code you have posted will not compile for too many reasons, and that makes it hard to determine what the problem in the code you are not showing is.

Comment: As @Neil said, if there is a problem in your code, you have to show us your code, not some different code you just wrote for our sake and which doesn't reproduce the problem (or which introduces new problems). Otherwise, we have no clue which of the errors are *real*, and which ones exist only in the retyped version.

Answer (score 2):

Your `x,y,z` are `private` members, and you are trying to access them from outside a class. Either make your `point`s `struct`s, or make your `x,y,z` `public`, or provide setters/getters for them.

EDIT:
Couple more things about your code:

1. Do **not** inherit your `class List` from `std::list`, standard containers are **not** meant to be used as base classes. If you need a special function that's not available in `std::container`, provide a free function which can do that, instead of inheriting from it.
2. Considering the type of question here, implementing your own container is probably not the best idea. Use some standard one, there's plenty of [them](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/), and they will most likely fit your needs.
3. When inheriting one class from another, the base class should normally be `virtual`.
4. `Point3D` isn't **kind of** `Point2D`, it's more like `Point2D` and `Point3D` **are kind of** Point. To me this kind of inheritance would make a bit more sense.

And just to stop guessing the compiler error you have there, give a try to this code, I think it's approximately what you're looking for.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Point
{
public:
    Point() {}
    virtual ~Point() {}

    virtual void some_function_relevant_to_all_points() {}

private:
    // maybe some members here
};

class Point2D : public Point
{
public:
    Point2D(double x, double y)
        : x_(0),
          y_(0)
    {}
    ~Point2D() {}

private:
    double x_;
    double y_;
};

class Point3D : public Point
{
public:
    Point3D(double x, double y, double z)
        : x_(x),
          y_(y),
          z_(z)
    {}
    ~Point3D() {}

    double get_x() const {return x_;}
    double get_y() const {return y_;}
    double get_z() const {return z_;}

private:
    double x_;
    double y_;
    double z_;
};

class Compare3DPointByX
{
public:
    bool operator()(const Point3D *lhs, const Point3D *rhs) const
    {
        return lhs->get_x() < rhs->get_x();
    }
};

class DeleteElement
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T *arg)
    {
        delete arg;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point3D *> points3d;
    points3d.push_back(new Point3D(4,5,6));
    points3d.push_back(new Point3D(1,2,3));

    std::cout << "point 1:" << points3d[0]->get_x() << "\n";
    std::cout << "point 2:" << points3d[1]->get_x() << "\n";

    std::sort(points3d.begin(), points3d.end(), Compare3DPointByX());

    std::cout << "point 1:" << points3d[0]->get_x() << "\n";
    std::cout << "point 2:" << points3d[1]->get_x() << "\n";

    std::for_each(points3d.begin(), points3d.end(), DeleteElement());
    return 0;
}
```

Rest of functionality you can add yourself, this example is just to give you the idea, how it might be implemented.

Hope it helps, good luck.

Comment: Must be written, thanx

class compareByX
{
bool operator () (3DPoint *p1, 3DPoint *p2) const
{
return p1->getX() < p2->getX();   //Compilation error
}
}

Comment: I don't agree at all with point number 3. What's the rationale?

Comment: @Manuel, as I said in the answer "_should normally_ be virtual", not "must". Say if Ian would be making a `std::vector<Point *>` like `push_back(new Point3D(1, 2, 3))` and delete pointers to base, `Point` would better provide virtual destructor thus becoming virtual. Contrary to that, `boost::noncopyable` being inherited privately by non-copyable objects has no need to be virtual, as no one does something like `boost::noncopyable *a = new nc_object(x, y);`, and to guarantee that provides protected ctor/dtor. Does that explain what I said?

Comment: So you mean that the base class should have a virtual destructor? That I agree with.

Answer (score 0):

- Classes and structure definitions should be followed by a `;`
- Identifier names cannot start with a digit

Comment: Of course, instead of 3DPoint must be Point3D... Error occurred rewriting the text on the page... But the source code on my PC is written correctly :-).

Comment: How do we know you haven't made other mistakes during this rewriting process?

Comment: @Ian: Post the actual code, if you care about actual answers.

Answer (score 0):

I correct the code (thans for checks), the same question....

```
class Point3D : public Point
{
double z;
public:
Point3D(double x, double y, double zx) : Point(x,y){z(zz);}
...
}

class compareByX
{
bool operator () (Point3D *p1, Point3D *p2) const
{
return p1->getX() < p2->getX();   //Compilation error
}
}


class List: public list<Point3D *>
{
...
}


int main()
{
List l;;
l.push_back(new Point3D(1,2,3));
l.push_back(new Point3D(4,5,6));
sort(l.begin(), l.end(), compareByX);  
}
```

Comment: This is still not valid C++.  The Point3D constructor contains two syntax errors and your class definitions are not terminated.

It is highly likely that the changes you have clearly made to the code will hide the cause of the bug.  Please post some code that you have actually compiled and run.

Comment: I have spent the last 10 minutes or so trying to read your mind and duplicate your problem.  I have failed; I managed to get a similar error message, but removing the consts did not then cause my code to compile.  Sorry, but the ball is firmly in your court as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Ian - Please edit your original question instead of correcting it with additional answers like this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort a `std::list` like that, you'll need something that supports random access like a `std::vector`. Either that or use the `sort` member function:

```
l.sort(compareByX());
```

Note the parantheses I've added to `compareByX`, you need to construct a functor and that's what the parentheses are for.

Also, you have to make your `operator()` a public member function so that the `sort` algorithm can call it. The simplest way to achieve this is making your functor a struct:

```
struct compareByX
{
    bool operator () (Point3D const *p1, Point3D const *p2) const
    {
        return p1->getX() < p2->getX();   
    }
};
```

I suspect that you'll also have to make your `getX` member function public but that's difficult to tell because you're not showing that part of your code.

Finally, I don't think you need pointers/heap allocation for this particular example. Your program will be faster and more robust if you create your points on the stack.

PS: please post real code next time, it will make it much easier for those trying to help.